# Returning distinct email addresses of multiple users with duplicate emails

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I have a database that has the following fields

```
Create table users
{
id int NOT NULL,
username varchar(255),
email varchar(255),
signup_date date,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
}
Create index user_index
On users (username)
```

The database allows multiple users to have same usernames since I have not included the unique keyword.
I wrote a SQL query that would generate a list of the usernames and the most recent signup_date for that username, for all usernames that have multiple instances in the table.

```
select username, MAX(signup_date)
group by username
```

But I also need to write a query that will generate a list of unique email addresses for all the usernames returned from the above query and I came up with the following:

```
select distinct email
From users
Group by username
Having max(signup_date)
```

My question is do I need to write a condition after the Having statement ? Or do I simply need to omit the Having clause and this will give me the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query:

```
select username, MAX(signup_date)
from users
group by username;
```

is going to return *all* user names.  You have no filters.  Your goal is "I also need to write a query that will generate a list of unique email addresses for all the usernames returned from the above query".  This is all unique email addresses.  For that:

```
select distinct email
from users;
```

I think your original query should be:

```
select username, MAX(signup_date)
from users
group by username
having count(*) > 1;
```

In order to find duplicates.  To get all email address on the duplicates, using a `where` clause:

```
select distinct email
from users u
where u in (select username
            from users
            group by username
            having count(*) > 1
           )
```

To get all email address by user, try:

```
select username, max(signupdate),
       group_concat(distinct email separator ', ' order by signup_date desc)
from users
group by username
having count(*) > 1;
```

This will give you all emails for all users as a comma separated list, along with the max signup date.

To get all users by email address:

```
select email, 
       group_concat(distinct username separator ', ' order by signup_date desc)
from users
group by email
```

Comment: THe thing is, users are permitted multiple users to signup with same usernames due to some reason and I am trying to eliminate that. so we are catching the users with multiple usernames grouping by recent signp date. and in the next I am trying to get hold of the distinct email addresses of those users with similar usernames i get from my first query

Comment: @noobcoder . . . Perhaps you should delete this question and start over with a clearer explanation of what you are looking for.

Comment: So why not just select DISTINCT username, email?  When taking the MAX date you're removing the detail about usernames belonging to multiple people, so username is effectively useless.